# Android development setup when using USB Host mode

Tags: android, galaxy, galaxy-tab

I am a relatively new Android developer but have gotten pretty familiar with the SDK, using LogCat, etc. However, I'm now working on an app (for a Galaxy Tab 7-plus) that utilizes USB Host mode to talk to an external USB device and I've run into an issue.

My question is: What is an ideal environmental setup that will allow me to take advantage of all of the SDK tools (adb, debug, LogCat, DDMS, and so forth) when I am unable to be connected to my PC via USB (since the external USB device my tablet is talking to is using my tab's only USB port)?

Is there an emulator available somewhere (I've searched in vain) that will allow me to simulate USB Host mode using a USB port on my PC?

Do I need to go to some type of on-board logging app?

Is there some kind of 30-pin splitter available so I can connect to both the external device and my PC?  (I'm guessing this is impossible, but I'm a hardware idiot... in addition to a run-of-the-mill idiot).

Thanks in advance for your help!

-KR

Comment: If the tablet is rooted you can use AdbWireless (Application on the Market)

Comment: Follow up... Ended up rooting the device and using AdbWireless.  Great app!  Thanks, SeRPRo.  Repost as an answer and I'll vote accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I posted in the comments, If the tablet is rooted you can use AdbWireless (Application on the Market)

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done without rooting. Google/Android officially supports this, as described at the bottom of this page:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/index.html

But AdbWireless is easier if you are rooted.

Comment: Thanks!  That was way hidden in the developer docs, eh?  Much appreciated.